# getting B-tree from CSV file for particular input

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, sed, awk

I have a CSV file with following contents

```
100001,0,top
100002,100001,left
100003,100001,middle
100004,100001,right
100005,100002,left
100006,100002,right
100007,100002,middle
100008,100003,left
100013,100003,right
100011,100003,middle
100014,100003,left
100025,100003,right
100020,100003,middle
```

Say first field is memberID, 2nd is memberof (refers memberID of same file of some above record) &  3rd postion ie left or middle or right
This is like B-tree Raw data 100001 on top which have its left middle and right branches

my expected output is

```
level1
100001(parent),100002,100004,100003

level2
100002(parent),100005,100006,100007
100004(parent),100014,100025,100029
100003(parent),100009,100013,100011

level4
......
```

there can be more than 100 records in the input file so there can be more than 5 levels if search starts from top.

Output should be members of heirarchy which are below input value. (say if I give 100003 it should give its members below him not above)

I tried inserting in mysql and try to query it recursively it became more complex and time consuming.

I believe `awk` & `sed` commands can help but I don't have much handson & practise on those.

I am looking for some `awk` or `sed` command or bash or shell script that can achieve this.

Its like Binary Search first then get B-tree from input.

For better understanding please check diagram (for every member there will be left right middle but not more than 3 members in immediate below level)

My failure attempt code 1 with mysql

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1;

left='';
middle='';
right='';
level=0
function getchild () {

left=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from mtree where pid=$1 and pos='left'");
middle=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from mtree where pid=$1 and pos='middle'");
right=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from btree where pid=$1 and pos='right'");
#level=$(($level+1));
#return $level;

}

getchild $input;
echo "$input,$left,$middle,$right"
```

My failure code 2 with grep

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1;

left='';
middle='';
right='';
level=0
function getchild () {

left=$(grep ",$1,left" filename);
middle=$(grep ",$1,middle" filename);
right=$(grep ",$1,right" filename);

}

getchild $input;
echo "$input,$left,$middle,$right"
```

Now I am gazling how can I get sublevels of each left middle & right (recursive till no elements down)

[image: diagram]

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Barmar: I underdstand, I posted my code yesterday which I tried via quering mysql & that question got downvoted 3 times with no answer for many hours

Comment: `#!/bin/bash

input=$1;

left='';
middle='';
right='';
level=0
function getchild () {

left=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from mtree where pid=$1 and pos='left'");
middle=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from mtree where pid=$1 and pos='middle'");
right=$(mysql -uroot -p"passwd" -Ddbname -s -N -e "select mid from btree where pid=$1 and pos='right'");
#level=$(($level+1));
#return $level;

}

getchild $input;
echo "$input,$left,$middle,$right"
`

Comment: gazeld for hours for calling function recursively but can't get it right

Comment: Please put code in the question, it's totally unreadable in comments because there's no formatting.

Comment: I added my code for level 1.. I am just scratching my head how can I drill down to sublevels

Answer (score 1):

You can start from this :

```
 awk -F , '{a[$2]=a[$2]==""?$1:a[$2] FS $1}END{for (i in a) print i,"(parent),",a[i]}' infile.csv
```

result:

```
0 (parent), 100001
100001 (parent), 100002,100003,100004
100002 (parent), 100005,100006,100007
100003 (parent), 100008,100013,100011,100014,100025,100020
```

Comment: Wonderful for start. Let me check if it works on test records with more data

Comment: now what if I want to get tree for some input value say 100003 I want its subtrees and its sub-sub tree and all

Comment: you need provide the detail what input file you have and expect output.

Comment: Actually that file is like database for me. I want to call the functions recursively to get any input value

say if I enter 10003 it should give my immediate tree and succeeding tree data.